# Regex that return the tab separated words in c#

Tags: c#, regex

i write a code  that return a words that separated by tab

```
const string input = "Lorem ipsum        dolor        sit %download%#456 amet, consectetu";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Regex expression = new Regex("\tw+\t");
            var results = expression.Matches(input);
            foreach (Match match in results)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(match);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

but this code does not work properly.
help me
thanks in advace

Comment: "Does not work properly"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your existing code could be fixed by making your regex `[^\t]+`.  By matching everything that is not a tab, you will get the tab-separated words.

However, you should really use [`Regex.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy.aspx) for this.

```
results = Regex.Split(input, @"\t+");
```

Comment: Or even `String.Split` with `RemoveEmptyEntries` set.

Answer (score 2):

If it's just tabs, why are you using a regex? Just use `String.Split`:

```
input.Split(new[] { '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you shure words in string are delimited by tabs or may be there are spaces?

Comment: -1 this should be a comment, not an answer.  And the code given by the OP would not work on data that is delimited by tabs, so there is no reason to question that.